# error log for papercut crash

Tags: 12.04, package-management, python, log, error-handling

it looks like [papercut](http://freecode.com/projects/papercut) is causing some problems after an upgrade:

[image]

Where is this log located?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: You need  to update your Ubuntu , guessed from image since  Apport is currently at `2.0.1-0ubuntu12`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the excerpt below from the default settings.py of papercut (found at http://src.gnu-darwin.org/ports/news/papercut/work/papercut-0.9.13/settings.py.html ), you are likely to find the log file (if any) at `/usr/local/share/papercut/logs/papercut.log` .

```
# full path for where Papercut will store the log file
log_path = "/usr/local/share/papercut/logs/"
# the actual log filename
log_file = log_path + "papercut.log"
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this, thank you for the response.